# Increase a width of a certain div by 10% while hovering on another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to achieve the following:

while hovering on a certain div (class="up"), i would like another div (class="bar") increase its width by 10%, and while hovering another div (class="down"), decrease its width (class="bar") by 10%.

I have this so  far:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(function(){
 $(".bar").css({
     'backgroundColor': 'red'
 }).hover(function () {
      $(this).stop().animate({
               width: '+=10%'
     }, 350).addClass('shadow');
 }, function () {
     $(this).stop().animate({
         width: '200px'
     }, 350).removeClass('shadow');
 });
});//]]>  

</script>
```

But as i am quite new to JS, i cant figure out how to amend it to suit my needs.
I need it to trigger once i hover a different div then the actual resized div, also i need to use the actual divs with as the .stop().animate width.
and i need to have both increase in width (while hovering on div with class "up", and decrease while hovering class "down")

will appreciate your assistance on the matter.

thanks in advance.

Comment: `hover()` is just a shortcut for the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events, if you use those events separately you can achieve what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the hover listener should be attached to up and down classes not bar

```
var bar = $('.bar'),
    originalWidth = bar.width();

$('.up').hover(function(){
  changeBarWidth( 1.1 * originalWidth,true);
},function(){
  changeBarWidth(originalWidth,false);
});

$('.down').hover(function(){
  changeBarWidth( .9 * originalWidth ,false);
},function(){
  changeBarWidth(originalWidth,false);
});

function changeBarWidth(x,addShadow){
  bar.stop().animate({
    width: x
  }).toggleClass('shadow',addShadow);
}
```

http://jsbin.com/mupomilo/1

Comment: Thanks for the help Daniel, the code looks good, the only thing that is missing is the  $(this).stop().animate({ part, the "bar" width should return to the original (bar width), when none of the elements are hovered.

again, thank you so much!

Comment: one last thing if you dont mind, i would like it to do the decreasing when i hover from "up" straight to "down" without hovering outside the div, same the other way around.

so when i hover the "up" and then straight on "down", the bar should increase (first hover) and then go back to original and decrease (on second hover), same the other way.

Answer (score 0):

Your hovering action should be on up, not on the bar itself...

something like:

```
$(function(){
var $myel = $('.bar');
 $(".up").hover(function () {
  $myel.stop().animate({
           width: '+=10%'
  }, 350).addClass('shadow');
 }, function () {
 $myel.stop().animate({
     width: '200px'
 }, 350).removeClass('shadow');
});
});
```

Also you should really consider upgrading your jquery version.  1.6 is VERY out of date.

Comment: Brian thank you as well....regarding upgrading te jquery, will it be enough to simply change the src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js"> or will it require code changes as well?

Comment: Depending on how your remaining code is written is could require modifcation.

Comment: Hey Daniel, 
I was trying to embed this code on my wordpress site, but seems that i have an jquery conflict. i already have a call for jquery in the  theme: 
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://hambareshet.co.il/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.0'></script>

but it is a newer version, and the script doesnt work with the new one, can you pinpoint what should i rewrite in your code so it will work with the 1.11 jquery version?

thanks again